# How to make one word to show as Bold in a Ternary Operator?

Tags: javascript, html, jsx

How can I make the word `Full` display as Bold in the ternary operator below? If I change it in the `span` it will make the word `enrolled` and `spots` show as bold as well and I don't want that. What's the way to do it?

```
<span
  style={{
    flexGrow: 1,
    color: "lightgrey",
    fontSize: "12px",
    marginLeft: "10px"
  }}
>
  {e.enrolledNum / e.total_spots >= 1
    ? 'Full'
    : `${e.enrolledNum} enrolled ${""} / ${""} ${
        e.total_spots ? e.total_spots : "0"
      } spots`}
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a `strong` tag, or if that's not what you mean semantically, some other inline element with a class that makes it bold.

For instance:

```
<span
  style={{
    flexGrow: 1,
    color: "lightgrey",
    fontSize: "12px",
    marginLeft: "10px"
  }}
>
  {e.enrolledNum / e.total_spots >= 1
    ? <strong>Full</strong>
    : `${e.enrolledNum} enrolled ${""} / ${""} ${
        e.total_spots ? e.total_spots : "0"
      } spots`}
</span>
```